# C# Selenium ChromeWebDriver Constructor never returns

Tags: c#, selenium

This is my code:

```
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
        options.AddArgument("url=data:,");

        _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
        
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
```

When I run my code, the `new ChromeDriver(service, options)` call never returns.
Although the browser driver and browser both launch and it redirects to the data; url. But `_driver` is left null forever and the next line never executes.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with edge?

Comment: This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) says you need a different driver for Edge.

Comment: You are using the wrong web driver. ChromeDriver works with Google Chrome. You need to download and use the driver specific to Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
 var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
        options.AddArgument("url=data:,");
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);    
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
```

There is couple of problem with this.

1. You are providing binary for Edge instead of chrome
2. you created new instance of chrome with `_driver` but you are using `driver` use `_driver` instead.